# Continuity of Distance Function on $\mathbb{R} $

Tags: functions, continuity

This is a question in Foster's Analysis 1 Practice Book.

Let $M$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

The function $d: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
is defined by $d(x) := \inf ${$|x-y|: y \in M$}, $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Need to show that $d$ is continuous on
$\mathbb{R}$.

For definiteness we show that $d$ is continuous at $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $x, y$ be real and $y\in M$.
We have
$|x-y|\le |x-x_0|+|x_0-y|$ and $d(x)\le |x-y|$.

Hence

$$d(x) \le |x-x_0|+|x_0-y|.$$

For $y \in M$ and $x, x_0$ fixed, the right-hand side is bounded below by $d(x)$.

Consider $\inf_{y\in M}$ of the right-hand side.

Then,
recall the definition of the infimum as the largest lower bound,

$$d(x) \le |x-x_0|+d(x_0),$$

or

$$d(x) - d(x_0) \le |x-x_0|.$$

Similarly, interchanging $x$ and $x_0$ we finally get

$|d(x) - d(x_0)|\le |x-x_0|$.

Choose $\delta =\epsilon$ and we are done.

Kindly check if correct. Thank you.

Any comments are welcome.

Note:

@Afntu commented that $d$ is even Lipschitz continuous ($L=1$).

Comment: Yes, your proof looks fine. This same idea is enough to say this function $d$ is also uniformly continuous.

Comment: @Afritu. Now that you mention uniform continuity, the above shows that d is even Lipschitz continuos with Lipschitz constant L=1. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Yes, I mean that as it is Lipschitz, so it is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Thanks for bringing it up, well worth while!

Comment: @Afritu. Added a note at the very end of the problem. Hope it is OK with you.

Comment: It is fine, but it is Afntu, not Afritu :)

Comment: @Afntu. So sorry, fixed it:)